# Using a Hidden Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sp-msforeachdb

I am trying to use the following stored procedure to obtain databases from a server.  However, I just want the databases created from a month ago.  What do I have to do to make this work?

Here is the code:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'IF ''?'' like ''z%'' 
BEGIN
  print ''?''
END'
```

I just want the databases that begin with Z that were created during a certain month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this instead.

```
select name
    from sys.databases
    where name like 'z%'
        and create_date >= dateadd(mm,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: the problem is, i'm trying to iterate through several databases and trying not to use a cursor or loop.  i've tried your code before within a cursor and it took a while to gather the data I needed.

Comment: @Jeff: Not sure I follow. `sp_msforeachdb` *is* a cursor under the hood. You can see this for yourself by running: `sp_helptext 'sp_msforeachdb'`

Comment: @Jeff: Joe Stefanelli is giving you a way to solve your problem without cursors or looping. He's selecting from a system catalog, which is a view that you can query. Unless the question changes, I'd say this is an answer. Does it not give what you want?

Comment: +1. This may not answer the OP's expectations, but certainly answers the question.